# how to apply multi-command in the yaml?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I got this error message, but I don`t understand Why?

plz look at **command:, argu:**

[Offical Document Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/)

> error: error validating "jenkins.yaml": error validating data:
>   [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.initContainers[0].args[0]):
>   invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.args: got "array",
>   expected "string",
>   ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.initContainers[0].command[0]):
>   invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.command: got "array",
>   expected "string"]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn
>   validation off with --validate=false

jenkins.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  labels:
    app: jenkins
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
        tier: jenkins
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: jenkins
      initContainers:
      - image: lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:v1.11.2
        name: kubectl-config
        command:
        - ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
        - ["usermod -aG docker jenkins; /kubectl-config-context.sh"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kubeconfig
          mountPath: "/root/.kube"
        - name: kubectl-jenkins-context
          mountPath: "/kubectl-config-context.sh"
          subPath: "kubectl-config-context.sh"
      containers:
      - image: 127.0.0.1:30400/jenkins:latest
        name: jenkins
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kubeconfig
          mountPath: /var/jenkins_home/.kube
        - name: docker
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
        - name: jenkins-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: jenkins
      volumes:
      - name: kubectl-jenkins-context
        configMap:
          name: kubectl-jenkins-context
          items:
          - key: kubectl-config-context.sh
            path: kubectl-config-context.sh
      - name: kubeconfig
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: docker
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
      - name: jenkins-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jenkins-claim
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are defining yaml array in a wrong way, command and args needs to be as follow:

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
args: ["usermod", "-aG", "docker", "jenkins", ";", "/kubectl-config-context.sh"]
```

Comment: thanks to your reply, but i got a same error.  Invalid ~~~~~

Comment: @soultree if you tried to copy and paste the code that I posted, you can retry now, because I had typo and it's fixed now.

Comment: Just a heads up, the suggested answer breaks the 80 character limit for the `args` field. An alternative: https://ibb.co/HXpy52J
nb. each element of `arg` is indented.